# Type or Namespace 'var' could not be found

Tags: c#

I'm working on an inline page to display some course information and keep getting a compilation error with the use of 'var'.

Can you check the following line of code and recommend ideas on fixing it.

```
//Get basic template details
using (var objConn = new SqlConnection(strConnection))
{
objConn.Open();
```

My imported namespaces look like as follows.

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Text" %
```

Any ideas?

EDIT

Version of .Net on the server - Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0

Thanks.

Comment: The `var` keyword is case-sensitive. Did you write `Var`?

Comment: Post exact code or exact error message, one of them isn't the real one.

Comment: What version of C# are you using?  `var` didn't exist before 3.0.

Comment: I have a feeling that the IIS version is using 2.0 rather than later versons of .Net

Also ignore my case sensitive spelling in the original query, it's lower case in the code.

Comment: In your Visual studio, Right click on project, go to properties, Under application see the framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll either need to switch to using C# 3.0 and .NET Framework 3.5, or you'll need to stop using the `var` keyword and specify the correct type, such as:

```
using (SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(strConnection))
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that it's not a simple Uppercase/lowercase typo since you typed it correctly in your code snippet.

Go to you project. Right Click -> Properties & check what version of the .NET Framework you're targeting for. The `var` keyword is only availble in C# 3.0 onwards.

Some other things to check. Check the compiler version in your web.config (if it's set). See this quesiton: [Error using 'var' after upgrading to Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086898/error-using-var-after-upgrading-to-visual-studio-2010)

And also check what version of ASP.NET you're using under IIS/Application Pools.

Answer (score 0):

You should import "System"

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
```

Comment: `var` is a keyword. not a type which lives in a namespace. This should have no effect.

Comment: You are right, I kind if assumed System names space might be needed in the code, that is interacting with DB and hence, that could cause errors.